# How to upload file from other pc to server directory using Blazor server side

Tags: blazor, server-side

I am trying to upload from the other pc and upload/store a file in server directory, but in fact my code is uploading in wwwroot
[Please see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCZAN.png)

Comment: What code? Post the code as *text* in the question itself. Images can't be compiled or googled. A web application's working directory *is* `wwwroot` which is a **very good thing** - it reduces the chance that a bug would allow someone to write outside the web app's folder. In fact, the application pool account has no permission to write outside that folder.

Comment: You'll have to use an absolute path to save outside `wwwroot` *and* ensure the apppool account has permission to write to that file